# Как отключить оптимизацию в Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить оптимизацию компилятора в среде Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 2):

### Вам нужно добавить флаг -O0 в флаги компилятора.

Для этого вам нужно открыть меню: "Build options -> Compiler settings -> Other options" , и там прописать влаг -O0.